# job-dsl - How to pass credentials while creating jobs from gitlab repo branches?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am creating a jobs for each application branches from github. 
I am not sure how to pass the credentials to the repo link?

```
import groovy.json.*

def project = 'app-ras'
def branchApi = new URL("https://gitlab.etctcssd.com/sdadev/${project}/branches")
def branches = new JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())
branches.each {
def branchName = it.name
def jobName = "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
job(jobName) {
    scm {
        git("https://gitlab.etctcssd.com/sdadev/${project}.git", branchName)
    }
  }
}
```

Our project is secure project in gitlab, so how can I pass the credentials in this case?

I am sure it would redirect to login page. But I am not sure how to handle this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will work in the following way:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def project = 'app-ras'
def branchApi = new URL("https://gitlab.etctcssd.com/sdadev/${project}/branches")
def branches = new JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())

branches.each {
    def branchName = it.name
    String jobName = "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/', '-')
    job(jobName) {
        scm {
            git {
                branch(branchName)
                remote {
                    url("https://gitlab.etctcssd.com/sdadev/${project}.git")
                    credentials("HERE")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try to substitute `HERE` with plain credentials (a kind of an access token) or with credential ID (of type *Secret text*) defined under `Jenkins` -> `Credentials`.

Also, are you using gitlab or github?

**EDIT**

So as far as I understood you have problems with fetching the branches names not with the Jenkins DSL. [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/branches.html#list-repository-branches) you can see how to fetch branches from gitlab. In groovy in can be done in the following way:

```
URLConnection connBranches = new URL("https://gitlab.etctcssd.com/sdadev/${project}/branches").openConnection()
connBranches.setRequestProperty("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "PASTE TOKEN VALUE HERE")
new JsonSlurper().parse(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connBranches.getInputStream())))
```

Comment: here is the error:  "groovy.json.JsonException: " i think my git lab branch api url is not correct.

Comment: Thank you So much. i was trying the wrong url for getitng branches. When i used this link it worked. `https://gitlab.etctcssd.com/api/v4/projects/34785/repository/branches`     where 34785 is the project id